# raspberrypi - recover innodb data from 32 bit mariadb server to 64 bit server

Tags: raspberry-pi, data-recovery, mariadb

After a system crash of my raspberrypi 3B+ (32 bit, OS buster) I could not recover madiadb (version: 10.3.31) data on localhost for several virtual hosts. I had to buy a new raspberrypi 4 with 64 bit architecture (OS bullseye). I tried several ways to recover the data.

(1) Simply copying data from »/var/lib/mysql/« of the pi3 system to the pi4 system was not successful (»cold backup« as recommended in »[MariaDB Backups Overview for SQL Server Users](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-backups-overview-for-sql-server-users/)«).

(2) I tried to purge mariadb (64 bit, 10.5.3) and install the old version 10.3.31, but I couldn't find a 64 bit deb-package for installation. It seems to be outdated for the 64 bit architecture.

(3) Dumps on sql-format are not the latest ;))

How can I get Maria running again ?? It is really important to me !

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Many thanx
Walter

Comment: "was not successful": in what way? Also, is /var/lib/mysql the actual mariadb database directory as configured in `datadir` in your /etc/mysql/my.cnf? I ask since /var/lib is usually on the SD card, one would go through lengths to not put database files on there – there's few storage media types less suited for typical long-term small-IO random location storage load. To say this explicitly to avoid future pain: *Don't store your database on your SD card*.